# findstr command not searching regex of a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I need to find an exception string in logs, but my log file names have a pattern.
like ABC_21-2-2023.log, ABC_21-2-2023.log.1, ABC_21-2-2023.log1, runlevel_ABC_21-2-2023.log

findstr /S /r %ErrorStr% "%LogFilePath%(MMI|run)?*.log.[0-9*]*"
"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a code snippet where variables a _defined_, Please fix unbalanced *quotation marks* as well. Follow https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: `findstr` does REGEX only with the search pattern, not with the files to search in.

Comment: Create a list of all the filenames you wish to search with dir /b /l, save the output to a file, and then use findStr with a regular expression on that file.